# GKE Ingress Won't Correctly Rewrite Paths

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I've recently set up  an nginx ingress in GKE, and somehow the ingress can't correctly rewrite the path for the mini-apps (laravel lumen) inside the target pods to resolve. The apps have a function called 'testing' which will print 'testing one' and 'testing two' for 'alpha' and 'beta'. the function should be accessible through `http://<base_url>/public/testing`.

There are two paths defined inside the ingress yaml, `/alpha/*` and `/beta/*` both of which will point to two services `lumen-alpha-svc` and `lumen-beta-svc`. I don't have any domain for this ingress so I left the 'host' in ingress undefined and the ingress should still be accessible by the external ip address provided by GKE for the ingress.

I tested the ingress by accessing `http://<external-ip-address>/alpha/public/testing/` for both ingress paths and I got HTTP Error 404, and this thing still makes me confused. So, I set up a new service called `path-check-svc` and add new path `/check/*` in ingress which will point to the service. The service then points to a nodejs program that will print url path. I tested the path by accessing `http://<external-ip-address>/check/something/` and the nodejs returned url path `/check/something/`. This makes me even more confused. Since the ingress path is defined with `/check/*` to redirect it to the path-check-svc, wouldn't that leave the path for the program to caught to only `/something/`? This made me realize that this is what caused the http error 404 in the lumen apps since it wasn't able to resolve `http://<external-ip-address>/alpha/public/testing/` because lumen apps doesn't know what `/alpha/` is.

So how should I defined the ingress so that the url path can be rewritten to the valid url path for the apps to catch. Thanks.

This is the yaml file for the kubernetes

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: lumen-alpha
  labels:
    app: lumen-alpha
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: lumen-alpha
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: lumen-alpha
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: husnurrsyafni/lumen-test-alpha:php
          name: lumen-test-alpha                 
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: lumen-beta
  labels:
    app: lumen-beta
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: lumen-beta
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: lumen-beta
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: husnurrsyafni/lumen-test-beta:php
          name: lumen-test-beta                 
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: lumen-alpha-svc
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: lumen-alpha
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: lumen-beta-svc
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: lumen-beta
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: lumen-ingress
  annotations:
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /alpha/*
        backend:
          serviceName: lumen-alpha-svc
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /beta/*
        backend:
          serviceName: lumen-beta-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, you haven't provided any relevant, testable code in this question and hence we have to figure out by coding the entire game ourselves. As a result, your question may be too broad.It would be great if you could [read these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a new question. Thanks.

Comment: oh sorry, my bad. I now attach the yaml file in the question. thanks.

Comment: did you create ingress-controller?   Can you also describe it in your post?

Comment: No, I didn’t. I thought GKE will automatically provide ingress controller, won’t it? I defined nginx in the annotations though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` annotation you need to create your own **nginx** [ingress controller](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/mandatory.yaml) and it's [service](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/provider/cloud-generic.yaml).

Or use helm (preferably):

```
helm install stable/nginx-ingress
```

Ingress controller provided by GKE doesn't support `rewrite-target`

Comment: Ah thanks man. So then the controller will be a deployment then? How do I tell ingress to use this controller instead of default GKE controller. What should I define for kubernetes.io/ingress.class section in yaml?

Comment: @HusnurRidhaSyafni yep, deployment will perform as ingress controller. I've update my answer with proper examples of how to use it. If you need more details, follow this link - https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/

Comment: @HusnurRidhaSyafni  also if you are using nginx annotation in your ingress object, you have to set `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this. Have a nice one mate!

Comment: Thank you and I'm sorry mate, I haven't quite followed your instruction. What I did is to set up an nginx deployment and make a service type loadbalancer for this, so this nginx will handle the rewriting rules. it works but I don't think this is the correct way to do this, and Ingress actually is what I want to have in the first place, so I will try this today and let you know.